# Finding the "Android class name" in "AndroidManifest.xml" generated by Unity3D

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-apps

When configuring a "Android Native App" in a Facebook app, they require the **Android Class Name**. If you created the Android APK from Unity3D, how do you know what class to use?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="--------------" android:versionName="1.02" android:versionCode="8">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <!-- ACTIVITIES -->
    <activity android:name="com.prime31.FacebookProxyActivity" />
    <!-- META-DATA -->
  </application>
  <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This field should be your main activity (associated with MAIN and LAUNCHER). In this case, I think it would be com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity.

This is mainly necessary if you use native deep links (so the FB app can create an intent that directly calls your activity). In that respect, any publicly accessible Activity in your app will do.

Answer (score 6):

The main activity's tag should contain an `intent-filter` tag with the action `android.intent.action.MAIN` and the category `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Description of the `intent-filter` tag (from documentation):

> Specifies the types of intents that an activity, service, or broadcast
>   receiver can respond to. An intent filter declares the capabilities of
>   its parent component — what an activity or service can do and what
>   types of broadcasts a receiver can handle. It opens the component to
>   receiving intents of the advertised type, while filtering out those
>   that are not meaningful for the component. Most of the contents of the
>   filter are described by its `<action>`, `<category>`, and `<data>`
>   subelements.
>
> For a more detailed discussion of filters, see the separate Intents
>   and Intent Filters document, as well as the Intents Filters section in
>   the introduction.

The main activity of an Android application has an `intent-filter` with the category `LAUNCHER` which basically tells that the activity can "launch the app" (in other words, that it is the launcher/entry).

The `activity` tag should look something like this:

```
<activity android:name="ActivityClassName" android:label="Activity title">
    <!-- The intent filter -->
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- The action -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <!-- The category -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

By looking at your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can conclude that the main Activity of your app is the `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity` Activity, because it contains an `intent-filter` matching those criterias.

Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 0):

Using "UnityPlayerProxyActivity" is no longer true for all unity versions. You may have to use "UnityPlayerActivity" instead.

Details:

If you export an Android project from unity you may find three classes in src:

- UnityPlayerActivity
- UnityPlayerNativeActivity
- UnityPlayerProxyActivity

"UnityPlayerProxyActivity" and "UnityPlayerNativeActivity" have been deprecated since Unity 5.0 beta12, thus you have to use "UnityPlayerActivity" instead.

In Facebook type in:

**[tld.yourdomain.game].UnityPlayerActivity**

Replace the [...] part with your app specifics of course. Attention: If you have some plugins/extensions that fiddle around with your manifest, then this may be different.

UPDATE:
In newer Versions of the Facebook SDK for Unity (tested with 7.9.4) you can simply search for "FacebookSettings" in your Assets folder and it will tell you what Class Name to use ("com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" for example).